# Theme.MaterialComponents colorPrimary not working

Tags: android, material-design

I'm using `Theme.MaterialComponent`, but it not affects to my actionBar, why?

**style.xml**

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/windowBackground</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

**colors.xml**

```
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#801336</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#510a32</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#ee4540</color>
    <color name="windowBackground">#2d142c</color>

    <color name="white">#FFF</color>
</resources>
```

[image]

Comment: please share the Manifest.xml as well

Comment: @0X0nosugar There, `android:theme="AppTheme"` in manifest, and no themes in activity

Comment: What don't work? Light or Dark? The issue I see is that the light `colorPrimary` works but the darks doesn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using just `Theme.MaterialComponents` as parent for your app theme will have no effect on the `ActionBar` like you noticed. You need to use one of the themes which inherit from the base theme.

- `Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar` if you want to use your own `Toolbar` as `ActionBar` and have a dark theme (white text on dark background colors)
- `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light` for a light theme (black text on light background) with an `ActionBar` generated by the runtime
- `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar` for a light theme with your own `Toolbar`, no auto-generated `ActionBar`
- `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar` for an overall light theme with the exception of a dark `ActionBar`
- `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight` for a [DayNight](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/appcompat-v23-2-daynight-d10f90c83e94) theme
- `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar` for a DayNight theme without auto-generated `ActionBar`
- `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar` for a DayNight theme with a dark `ActionBar`

Note: you may use any color, no matter what theme you choose. But if you choose for example  `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar` and set

```
 <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
```

then your `ActionBar` will be white and - since you said you have a dark `ActionBar` - the text will also be white. So it's up to you to make sure that there is enough contrast.